# Retrieve all ngModels within a transcluded directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to retrieve all ngModels within a transcluded directive. Is this the right way or is there a simpler solution to find the child model values?

Is there also a selector where i can use queries like this one ("input", "textarea", "select", ...)

The sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/tjjBEa1I1fIISvGbRz7e?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right approach. All your models are inside your $scope so why don't getting it from there directly?

For changes you shouldn't use jQuery like element.on('change', ...) style, instead bind an event listener to the model with $scope.$watch('model', ...) that would be the angular way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to disable all the inputs and clear their values when the 'Disable' checkbox is ticked?

I would recommend adding the [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) directive to your inputs and binding it to a property on your model.

You can easily clear the input values by moving them onto an object on your model and then clearing that property when the controls are disabled.

Updated version of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKRF3rfAB8EcSKEBEeKd?p=preview

Here is the updated code based on your example:

**app.js:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    // 1. Bind the 'Disable' checkbox's ng-model to this value.
    $scope.disabled = false;

    // 2. Move all your model data down one level onto the 'viewData' object.
    // Now we can change all the input values just by changing the `$scope.viewData` object.
    $scope.viewData = {
        user: {
            lastname: 'Doe',
            firstname: 'John'
        },
        checker: true,
        opt: 'Item 2'
    };

    // 3. Add a change callback on the 'Disable' checkbox to call this function.
    // Replace the $scope.viewData to change the input values.
    var originalData = null;
    $scope.disabledChanged = function() {
        if ($scope.disabled) {
            // Clear the previous object.
            originalData = $scope.viewData;
            $scope.viewData = null;
        } else {
            // Revert back to the previous object.
            $scope.viewData = originalData;
        }
    }
})
```

**index.html:**

```
<fieldset id="f">
    <legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" child-disable child-disable-root="f" ng-model="disabled" ng-change="disabledChanged()" /> Disable</label>
    </legend>
    <hr />
    <p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="viewData.checker" ng-disabled="disabled" /> Test</p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="viewData.user.firstname" ng-disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="viewData.user.lastname" ng-disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p><textarea ng-model="viewData.multi" ng-disabled="disabled"></textarea></p>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="viewData.opt" ng-disabled="disabled">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: My plan is to have one directive because there are multiple sections which can be disabled. The posted sample can be multiple times one below the other. Furthermore there are many views with different models which can be disabled. Therefore i thought a directive is a more generic and reusable approach and i don't repeat myself.
Do you think i should use ng-disabled und ng-change on all the views and sections? There is also no plan to restore the model.